# Pattern matching in brace expressions formulas

Tags: algorithm, tree, pattern-matching, expression, fsm

I have a long list of n (~50000) lines with formulas that look like that:

```
A(1, 2) = 54353
A(1, 2, 3) = 89327
A(1, B(1, 2)) = 8372
A(7, B(1, 3, 5)) = 6311
A(7, B(C(1, 3, 7), 2, C(1, 3), 5)) = 28490
B(A(1, C(5, 3)), 3, 8, D(1, 2)) = 39783
```

etc.

These formulas contain of literals (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, etc) and function calls (i.e. `A(x, y)` or `A(x, y, z)` or `B(x, y)`), where arguments of functions can be also either literals or other (nested) function calls. Functions (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`, etc) are fixed and there are not too many of them (may be around  a dozen).

Now I have run queries with either full formula or some pattern with `*` which ought to act as glob character, i.e:

```
A(1, 2) => [54353]
A(1, *) => [54353, 89327, 8372]
A(*, 3) => [89327]
A(*, B(*)) => [8372, 6311, 28490]
A(*, B(*, 3, *)) => [6311]
```

Basically, I have two questions:

1. How to do it *at all*: in fact, I don't know of a good basic pattern matching algorithm here. I've tried to convert expressions with * to regular expressions and it works for simple examples, but alas, fails for more intricate ones, i.e.:

   ```
   Converting:
   'A(*, B(*, 3, *))' => /^A\(.*, B\(.*, 3, .*\)\)$/

   True positive:
   'A(7, B(1, 3, 5))' =~ /^A\(.*, B\(.*, 3, .*\)\)$/

   False positive:
   'A(7, B(C(1, 3, 7), 2, C(1, 3), 5))' =~ /^A\(.*, B\(.*, 3, .*\)\)$/
   ```

   I feel that converting these brace expressions to reverse polish notation and then applying normal regular expression approach might help, but I'm not sure.
2. How to do it *fast*: any ideas how do it faster than doing ~50000 matches for every query are more than welcome. Is it possible to use some sort of FSM here?

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions are designed for [*Regular Languages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) (originally), while you are describing a [*Context Free Language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).

Your language is parse-able by a Deterministic [*Push-Down Automata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automata).

The idea is similar to a FSM, but in addition you have a [*stack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) that you can `push()` and `pop()` elements. 

Changing a state in the FSM is also depending on the head of your stack.

Comment: Indeed. Could you recommend some existing PDA implementations?